# Connect 4 Horizontal Victory Checking Error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been trying to solve this issue for a couple of days now... here's the code...

```
def checkhor(array):
    for x in range(1, 8):
        if (array[x] == "#") or (array[x] == "@") and (array[x] <= 4):
            if (array[x] == array[(x + 1)]) and (array[x] == array[(x + 2)]) and (array[x] == array[(x + 3)]):
                if turn == 0:
                    print "You Won!"
                    return True
                else:
                    print "You Lost..."
                    return True
```

... here's the error

```
File "/home/firearrow5235/PycharmProjects/Connect 4/Connect 4.py", line 132, in <module>
if checkhor(f):
  File "/home/firearrow5235/PycharmProjects/Connect 4/Connect 4.py", line 77, in checkhor
if (array[x] == array[(x + 1)]) and (array[x] == array[(x + 2)]) and (array[x] == array[(x + 3)]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

the points are which this error pops up is really sporadic... I can go a few rounds 
placing pieces in ANY of the seven slots without issues... I'll put my last input in...

```
['A', '#', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['B', '@', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['C', '@', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['D', '#', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['E', '@', '@', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['F', '@', '#', '#', 'O', '#', '#', 'O']
[' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
Enter the column you'd like to drop your piece in4
```

and I'll also add a board showing that it's not where the piece is that's the problem

```
Enter the column you'd like to drop your piece in5
['A', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['B', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['C', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['D', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['E', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['F', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '@', 'O', 'O']
[' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's a couple of things with your conditional:

```
if (array[x] == "#") or (array[x] == "@") and (array[x] <= 4):
```

If I understand your code correctly, the final check should be to make sure you don't go out of bounds with `x >= 4`, but you have `array[x] >= 4` instead.

Additionally, you might want to throw some extra parenthesis around the `or`:

```
>>> True or False and False
True
>>> (True or False) and False
False
```

Either of those could contribute to getting past the conditional, and then getting your `IndexError` when you try to index `x+3`

Comment: Oh! I see... yep... ok, having array[x] <= 4 was indeed my problem... Thanks! :)